# How to combine TF-IDF scores to be the equivalent of concatenating two strings

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf

I have a corpus of 5000 book titles and I am trying to perform some clustering on these. I am using the sklearn TfidfVectorizer library to generate the TF-IDF matrix for each title.

However, I now combine two of the titles (so "Book A" and "Book B" becomes "Book A Book B") and I am wondering if there is a way of getting the TF-IDF matrix for "Book A Book B" by combining the matrix for "Book A" and the matrix for "Book B".

I have tried recalculating the TF-IDF score again but this can take a lot of time and I would prefer if there was a quicker way of doing it since I actually need to do this several thousand times for different combinations of the titles.

The code below shows what I am doing right now.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=0, stop_words='english')

titles = list_of_strings

tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(titles)

# This gives a matrix roughly (5000, 20000)

new_title = titles[0] + ' ' + titles[1]

# Get the tfidf_matrix for the new_title
```

I would be great if there was something like:

```
matrix_for_book_a + matrix_for_book_b
```

and this gave the matrix for "Book A Book B" but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tf-idf matrices and it still be somewhat relevant, howewer, the vectors will be not normalized afterwards and normalization of them is by itself not easier than vectorization. For clustering data based on similarity score(which can be computed with tfidf) its highly recommended to work with normalized vectors. Also, keep in mind that if you really want to combine those two into one with just addition, their vocabularies have to be the same, otherwise it will make no sence(or even the dimentions would be different). Also the problem is with nature of tf-idf if  some term was in many documents in one dataset and in few in other, his added tf-idf score would probably not be as good and relevant as calculated from skratch. So my best suggestion to you is indeed as you said

> recalculating the TF-IDF score again

For 5000 titles (or 10000 if combined idk) it still won't take more than some reasonable time (depending from your machine, on mine around 5-10 mins) and then saving this matrix to not go over the calculations again will do you a great favour.